How can I create a single paged landscape document in officedown?
Intuitively, I would have thought that I just start and stop a landscape block. However, the landscape tags are introducing page breaks, hence creating a three page document where I only want one. Any ideas how I can create a single paged landscape document in officedown?
---
output:
  officedown::rdocx_document:
    base_format: "rmarkdown::word_document"
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
library(officedown) # 0.3.0
```

<!---BLOCK_LANDSCAPE_START--->

# A headline

And some text.

<!---BLOCK_LANDSCAPE_STOP--->


You can set the default orientation for the document in the YAML via page_size. However, to make this work I had to set the page_margins too, at least on one side, e.g. in the code below I opted for bottom.
---
output:
  officedown::rdocx_document:
    page_size:
      orient: "landscape"
    page_margins:
      bottom: 1
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
library(officedown)
```

# A headline

And some text.



Interesting, I had seen this as a solution here https://github.com/davidgohel/officedown/discussions/88 but it seems to have stopped working. Your workaround fixes it again. Do you think its a bug?

Yup. Looks like a bug to me. Encountered this solution only by accident. I just wanted to check whether setting page_margins has any effect.

https://github.com/davidgohel/officedown/issues/145

Thx for adding the link to the GH issue.
